# F# when should you use tuple and when should you use struct?

Tags: struct, f#, tuples, containers

What are the underlying differences between F# tuples and structs. They can both hold multiple variables, but I just want to know when one is used over the other.

To be more specific, I am trying to pass a bunch of parameters through a bunch of functions with a new variable being accumulated each time. For example, I start with param1 and pass it into func1 which returns (param1,param2). This tuple (or struct) then gets passed to func2 which returns (param1,param2,param3), and so on.

My current thoughts are this: with a tuple, I can always hold just the right amount of arguments, but I give up a uniform format for the data, and in the end, I would have to pack and repack a tuple of about 10 elements. With a struct, I have the advantage of uniformity of the parameters, but the problems is, I would have to null specify the parameters in the beginning.

Comment: This should be closed as : too broad, unclear what you are asking, and primarily opinion based

Comment: The knee-jerk answer is that in most languages: tuples are merely ordered whereas structs have named members. Which usually comes down to syntax overhead versus expressiveness, with the caveat that structs often need to be a formally defined type whereas tuples can be very informal. But a full answer would depend on the language and "better to use" is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using F#.

Comment: There is no *better*.  Idiomatic F# code regularly uses both, depending on the use case at hand. I'm going to update your title to *slightly* reduce the chances this question will get closed.  It's still likely too broad and opinion based though.  You should propose a specific use case within the question.

Comment: I think this might be a perfectly valid answer - in F#, tuples are reference types and structs are value types, which has some noteworthy implications!

Comment: Why are people on SO more obsessed with question taxonomy than with being helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In F#, tuples are represented using `Tuple<T1, T2>` which is a reference type. On the other hand, structures are value types and so they are allocated on stack rather than on the heap (which may sometimes be faster). So my general rules are:

- Tuples have nice syntactic support in F#, so use tuples by default because they make your code nicer. In most cases, the performance is similar and you do not need to worry about it (it depends on the use - tuples are not always slower).
- When your tuples get more complicated (say, more than 3 elements), it makes sense to use a type with named members (like a record or an object type).
- When allocating a large array of tuples or structs, it is better to use structs. You can either define your own struct or use standard .NET structs like `KeyValuePair<K, V>`.

To give an anecdotal evidence, in [Deedle](https://github.com/bluemountaincapital/deedle) we are using structs for the internals (time-series is stored as an array of structs), but not for the public API, which uses tuples.

Comment: From [Expert F# 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/expert-f-4-0/): "_Structs are often more efficient, but you should use them with care because the full contents of struct
values are frequently copied._" (There is also a short recommendation section on when to use value types in public APIs, but it corresponds to the one in this answer.)